# setting value to JSF component on a form

Tags: jsf

I have a UI form which has some hidden form fields on it. In some cases the value for the inputfields has to be set when the form is rendered. Right now I'm using inline javascript on the page to set the value to hidden form field.

```
 <h:inputHidden id="computeAction" value="#{backBean.property}"  />
 <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
      // <![CDATA[
           $('formId:computeAction').value ="true";            
      // ]]>
    </script>
```

I have to do this because I have to use the value attribute on form to create the binding to managed bean property. Is there a better to do this?

Comment: Your JS code won't work. The jQuery selector is broken.

Comment: Thank you, but that's not JQuery. We use prototype.js

Answer (score 0):

Just set it during (post)construction of the bean.

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class BackBean {

    private String property;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        property = "true";
    }

    // ...
}
```

If you make the bean `@ViewScoped`, you don't even need a `<h:inputHidden>` at all.

Comment: The value to be set is determined while the page is being rendered. For example I have two versions of JSF forms one of the form would want to set 'true' and the other wants to set 'false' on the same property.